# Flutter Future always return null

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

What is wrong in my code it always returns null

```
getLocation().then((r)  {
                          if (r != null) {
                            print("r=" + r.length.toString());
                          } else {
                            print("result is null");
                          } 
                        });



Future< List<double>> getLocation() async {
   // print("getLocation called");
      location = new Location();
    List<double> result=[];

      location.getLocation().then((loc) {

      result.add(loc.latitude);
      result.add(loc.longitude);
      result.add(4213);
      //  print(loc.latitude.toString() + "," + loc.longitude.toString() +"  l="+l1.length.toString());
      return result;

    }).catchError((e){
      return result;
    });
  }
```

Comment: please add some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning anything in your function, only in your `then` callback.
Since you are using async syntax anyway you can just go for:

```
Future< List<double>> getLocation() async {
  location = new Location();
  List<double> result=[];

  var loc = await location.getLocation();
  result.add(loc.latitude);
  result.add(loc.longitude);
  result.add(4213);
  return result;
}
```

I've taking error handling out of the code but you can just use try-catch if you want that.